# Stripe Payment - Uninstall nightmare

Tags: magento, stripe-payments

I tried to install STRIPE PAYMENT using the Installation guide found here:

https://stripe.com/docs/plugins/magento/install

Installation failed and I tried to uninstall it. I thought it was gone for good but I receive the following error message whenever I try to access "Simple Products":

```
1 exception(s):
```

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\Adminhtml\Source\BillingInterval does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\Adminhtml\Source\BillingInterval does not exist

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('StripeIntegratio...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('StripeIntegratio...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('StripeIntegratio...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('StripeIntegratio...', array()) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]
#5 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create('StripeIntegratio...') called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:641]
#6 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getSource() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php:1181]
#7 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->getSource() called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:679]
#8 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->setupAttributeMeta(&Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000002ca4b786000000004a5cc590#, 'subscriptions-by...', 1) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:397]
#9 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->getContainerChildren(&Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000002ca4b786000000004a5cc590#, 'subscriptions-by...', 1) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:370]
#10 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->addContainerChildren(array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' => array('formElement' => 'container', 'componentType' => 'container', 'breakLine' => false, 'label' => 'Frequency', 'required' => 0)))), &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000002ca4b786000000004a5cc590#, 'subscriptions-by...', 1) called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:345]
#11 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->getAttributesMeta(array(&Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000002ca4b785000000004a5cc590#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000002ca4b786000000004a5cc590#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000002ca4b78b000000004a5cc590#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000002ca4b78c000000004a5cc590#, &Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor#000000002ca4b78d000000004a5cc590#), 'subscriptions-by...') called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Eav.php:305]
#12 Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Eav->modifyMeta(array('product-details' => array('children' => array('container_status' => array('arguments' => array('data' => array('config' => 

*(Very long code error message #13/#14)*

#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('product_form', NULL, array('context' => &Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context#000000002ca4ba2f000000004a5cc590#, 'structure' => &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#000000002ca4b222000000004a5cc590#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:140]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Data\Structure#000000002ca4b222000000004a5cc590#, 'product_form', array('attributes' => array('group' => '', 'component' => '', 'aclResource' => '', 'visibilityCondit...' => array())), &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor#000000002ca4b24c000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:102]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#000000002ca4b67d000000004a5cc590#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000002ca4b635000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Reader\Context#000000002ca4b67d000000004a5cc590#, &Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Context#000000002ca4b635000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:343]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:89]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('menu') called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('menu') called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]
#27 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog:...') called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:24]
#28 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu('Magento_Catalog:...') called at [vendor/magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php:71]
#29 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php:24]
#30 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#31 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#32 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#33 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#34 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#35 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(&Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor#000000002ca4b563000000004a5cc590#, &Closure#000000002ca4b56b000000004a5cc590#, &Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#36 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#37 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#), NULL) called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Interceptor.php:39]
#38 Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#, &Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Interceptor#000000002ca4b563000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#41 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#42 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#43 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#), array(array('default_store_se...', 'page_cache_from_...', 'storeCookieValid...', 'install', 'configHash'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#44 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http#000000002ca4b1bc000000004a5cc590#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:136]
#45 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#46 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#47 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor#000000002ca4b1fe000000004a5cc590#) called at [index.php:39]
```

I do not know what I am missing here. I do not find a trace of STRIPE in my backend or in my server files.

Any advice would be greatly welcomed..!

Sincerely,
Toomas

Comment: If following the exact steps at https://stripe.com/docs/plugins/magento/install#uninstall left you in this state, I'd suggest checking that you didn't do any additional steps during the install (and if you did, undo those steps). If that doesn't help, [Stripe Support](https://support.stripe.com/email) officially supports the Magento plugins now and can likely assist.

Comment: Thank you but their support is very non-responsive. One thing I noticed now is that I cannot run:

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

I get the following error message:

`The  directory "/public_html/generateed/code/Magento" cannot Directory not empty`

Answer (score 4):

We had this same problem.  The module, `StripeIntegration` (setup version 1.6.0), leaves behind some traces in the database.

First, there are tables:

`stripe_customers`

and

`stripe_webhooks`

In our case, these were empty and were not interacting with anything.  What was causing the error was a record in the `eav_attribute` table.  Your installation may be different, but we found it by querying:

`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE source_model LIKE '%StripeIntegration%';`

This should show you the record.  As a bonus, you can see the class specification (`StripeIntegration\Payments\Model\Adminhtml\Source\BillingInterval`) in the record itself.  We deleted this record and everything worked that had been previously erroring.  We didn't end up having any references in the database to that attribute, however, if you do, that may make the removal more complicated.